# WPF polygon storyboard animation

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, storyboard

Trying to make exact animation from [FloatingMusicActionButton](https://medium.com/@timrijckaert/play-pause-stop-animated-vector-drawable-88a9df956d20)

My code till now:

```
<Grid Width="128" Height="128" Panel.ZIndex="1">
            <Ellipse Fill="Aqua"></Ellipse>
            <Polygon Fill="LightBlue" Stroke="Black" Name="TriOne" >
                <Polygon.Points>
                    <Point X="44" Y="32"></Point>
                    <Point X="44" Y="64"></Point>
                    <Point X="100" Y="64"></Point>
                    <Point X="100" Y="64"></Point>
                </Polygon.Points>
                <Polygon.Triggers>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Polygon.MouseUp">
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation 
                                    Storyboard.TargetName="{Binding ElementName=TriOne, Path=Points[0]}"
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="X"
                                    From="44" To="32"
                                    />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger>
                </Polygon.Triggers>
            </Polygon>
            <Polygon Fill="LightBlue" Stroke="Black" Name="TriTwo" >
                <Polygon.Points>

                    <Point X="44" Y="96"></Point> 
                    <Point X="44" Y="64"></Point>
                    <Point X="100" Y="64"></Point>
                </Polygon.Points>
            </Polygon>
        </Grid>
```

Application goes into break mode after clicking the polygon throwing:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll
>   '44,32' name cannot be found in the name scope of 'System.Windows.Shapes.Polygon'.

I'm new to WPF, if you know a better method of animating polygons please share a link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your animation cannot work because the `X` property of `Point` is not a dependency property.

Use a `Path` instead of a `Polygon` and animate the `PathFigure`s:

```
<Grid Width="128" Height="128" Panel.ZIndex="1">
    <Ellipse Fill="Aqua"></Ellipse>
    <Path Fill="LightBlue" Stroke="Black" Name="TriOne">
        <Path.Data>
            <PathGeometry>
                <PathFigure x:Name="fig" StartPoint="44, 32" IsClosed="True">
                    <LineSegment Point="44, 64"/>
                    <LineSegment x:Name="middle" Point="100, 64"/>
                    <LineSegment Point="100, 64"/>
                </PathFigure>
            </PathGeometry>
        </Path.Data>
        <Path.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Polygon.MouseUp">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <PointAnimation 
                            Storyboard.TargetName="fig"
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="StartPoint"
                            From="44,32" To="32,32"
                        />
                        <PointAnimation 
                            Storyboard.TargetName="middle"
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Point"
                            From="100, 64" To="90, 54"
                        />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Path.Triggers>
    </Path>
    <Polygon Fill="LightBlue" Stroke="Black" Name="TriTwo" >
        <Polygon.Points>

            <Point X="44" Y="96"></Point>
            <Point X="44" Y="64"></Point>
            <Point X="100" Y="64"></Point>
        </Polygon.Points>
    </Polygon>
</Grid>
```